# Connecting to AWS EC2 Container Service docker fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to set up EC2 Container Service. I use the following command:
`aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1` which gives me a docker login which looks something like this:

```
docker login -u AWS -p **VERY LONG KEY** -e none https://MYID.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

When I run this I get the following errors:

```
Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I am following their "FirstRun" tutorial which can be found [here](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=eu-west-1#/firstRun).

What am I doing wrong?

---

For reference: I have set up a IAM user and added the keys to in the `aws configure` command.

Comment: I got it working now. I belive the network I was on had some sort of firewall.

Comment: Good to note is also that you just got a warning (not an error) about a deprecated argument (-e) to the docker login command. Omit the "-e" arg and you shouldn't get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that your Docker daemon is not running on your Container instance.

You can do so by running the below command (ssh to your instance beforehand):

```
sudo docker -d &
```